# VBA macro not sorting all values

Tags: vba

I am sorting alphabetically by sector. The macro executes but it does often leave 1 value unsorted. For example it gives me this output:
The second data row is not sorted correctly.

```
| Security                        | Sector                   | Region   | Country   |
|---------------------------------|--------------------------|----------|-----------|
| Carlsberg   Class B             |  Consumer Staples        |  Europe  |  Denmark  |
| Broedrene   A & O Johansen Pref |  Industrials ERROR HERE  |  Europe  |  Denmark  |
| Jyske Bank                      |  Financials              |  Europe  |  Denmark  |
| Tryg                            |  Financials              |  Europe  |  Denmark  |
| Ringkjobing Landbobank          |  Financials              |  Europe  |  Denmark  |
| Demant                          |  Health Care             |  Europe  |  Denmark  |
| Novo Nordisk Class B            |  Health Care             |  Europe  |  Denmark  |
| Gn Store Nord                   |  Health Care             |  Europe  |  Denmark  |
| Nkt                             |  Industrials             |  Europe  |  Denmark  |
| Iss                             |  Industrials             |  Europe  |  Denmark  |
| Flsmidth And Co.                |  Industrials             |  Europe  |  Denmark  |
| A P Moller Maersk   Class B     |  Industrials             |  Europe  |  Denmark  |
| Vestas Wind Systems             |  Industrials             |  Europe  |  Denmark  |
| Dsv   Panalpina                 |  Industrials             |  Europe  |  Denmark  |
| Columbus                        |  Information Technology  |  Europe  |  Denmark  |
```

The code I use:

```
Dim tbl as ListObject
Set tbl = Sheets(1).ListObjects("Table1")
With tbl.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[Sector]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, 
         Order:=xlAscending
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
End With
```

The data in the table is dynamically inserted from an SQL query before it is sorted. I have left that code out. When I use *stopwatch* and manually go through each line it sorts correctly which makes me think it has something do with the timer. I tried `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))` and `DoEvents`, but neither solved the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `Sheets(1).Calculate`, to ensure that the Table has updated itself properly?  (Also, are you able to use an `ORDER BY` in the SQL Query to remove the requirement to sort in Excel?)

Comment: `Sheets(1).Calculate` worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>(Upgraded from a comment, so that the question can be marked as solved!)</sub>

Your code is trying to sort the Table before it has worked out what the new data in the table is!

Adding the line `Sheets(1).Calculate` will tell Excel to take a moment to work out what has changed on the Sheet, and the Data Table will update itself.  You can then sort the updated data.

This is not always an issue - by not recalculating the entire workbook after every line of code, it runs a **lot** faster.